# No CSS on Stack Overflow website

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

For the past week, the Stack Overflow website seems to be acting funny. The CSS is not loading which doesn't allow me to edit questions or simply use the website normally. However, other Stack Exchange sites work perfectly normally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like the mobile view. You should be seeing a "Full site" link to the bottom

Comment: Shall I answer my own question or do you want to answer it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the mobile view setting, which is available on the bottom of the screen. Just scroll down and click the "Full site" button.